# Create image cache for BlackBerry

Tags: image, blackberry, persistence, image-caching

My images should be cached so that they are not downloaded more than once.
They should only be updated if an image name is not currently stored locally.

How should an app cache images and use them locally without downloading again on BlackBerry?

Comment: You may use Hashtable example http://kickjava.com/749.htm

Answer (score 1):

Probably write your downloaded images to SDCard, then before redownload just check if the image is already present. However this could be not as simple as it may seem at a glance if you are new to file manipulation API on BlackBerry.